# Getting blank page after deploying React app to surge.sh

Tags: reactjs, surge.sh

I made a simple React app in Visual Studio Code and want to host it on a website which I am using surge.sh. When I deployed the app and head to the site, it just shows a blank page although the deployment was successful when I deploy it in my terminal.

Here are my steps that I did:

1. cd to root directory of my project
2. run `npm run build`
3. cd build
4. run `surge` command
5. provide {domain name}.surge.sh

I am new to using surge.sh. What might I have done wrong?

Comment: any errors in build process?

Comment: @Rikin No errors. The way I fixed it was to follow the above steps but with the addition of renaming the `index.html` to `200.html` and the it works. No idea why.

Comment: @Daredevil It should still have showed up at the root, but then the 200.html file also indicates that you want all routes to redirect to the index, because you’re managing the routing client side. More details are here: https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-200-page-for-client-side-routing

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step to resolve(only 4 surge):

```
npm run build
cd build
cp index.html 200.html
surge
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to your package.json scripts -

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "deploy": "npm run build && cp build/index.html build/200.html && surge build https://{domain_name}"
}
```

And then you can run this on a Terminal from the root of the project (anytime you need to deploy) using `npm run deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for my React projects, even with Router.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deploy-react-app-to-surge/

I deleted strings "*homepage*", "*deploy*", "*pre-deploy*" in file **package.json**,
built static version with 'npm run build', run '**surge**', added '**build**' to project path, added the **project name**

and BINGO! that's worked! no more blank screens and paths to-from who-knows-where

Projects was build as create-react-app in VS code